# How to get the view name or Id of an android view

Tags: android, python, androidviewclient

I'm currently developping code to make android phone test automation.
I have based my test engine using python and also the AndroidViewClient librairy developed by Diego Torres

I'm able to get the hierarchy of a view using the command :

```
    device, serialno = viewclient.ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
    vc = viewclient.ViewClient(device, serialno)
    for id in vc.getViewIds():
        attrs =  vc.findViewById(id)
        #print str(id) + "->" + str(attrs)
        WindowTree.append(str(id) + "->" + str(attrs))
```

It works fine. By the way my issue is that each view got its own hierarchy. As example, Call application can have the dial pad view and call log view.

Each of this view have their own hierarchy. I was able to identify each icons/texts fields with the its corresponding id but I still not find how to get the view name ??

Any idea ?

I would be able to react depending the view I am in.
If dial pad then Ids correspond to blablabla
If call log view the Ids correspond to blabla

I have tried to use "vc" to get view id but it's the same if I'm in the dial pad or call log screen. In that way, I do not have any way to know if I'm in dialpad or call log view

Comment: Can you be more specific about what are you expecting, perhaps giving an examples of expected vs. actual. What do you mean by *view name*, I guess it's not the *id* because you mentioned that *ids* are fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I need is to be able to know if I'm in the dial pad, call history or phonebook when accessing to the phone application.

If I'm already on the right view, I can get Ids of this view